# Alt tag being broken up by spaces. How to pass text?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

Trying to update an editor from FCKeditor from 2006 to (CKeditor 4) with a custom plugin made back then. I am almost there but when I try and insert an alt tag (alternative text) I get strange results as the alt tag has spaces. The editor breaks up the text value for the alt tag into various parts each time it hits a space. Here is my code snippet. The alt tag gets broken at the first space.

Quite new to this, any advice or help appreciated. :-)

Kind regards
Abbey

```
function onClose(){

    var imgUrl = hidFileName.value;
    var altTag = "this is a test";
    
        var result="<img src="+'<%=strImagePath%>'+imgUrl+" alt="+altTag+" >";
        var element = window.opener.CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( result );
        var CKEDITOR   = window.opener.CKEDITOR;   
        for ( var i in CKEDITOR.instances ){
           var currentInstance = i;
           break;
        }
        
        var oEditor   = window.opener.CKEDITOR.instances[currentInstance];     
        oEditor.insertElement(element);
        window.close();
    }
```

Comment: You need to properly wrap attribute values into _delimiters_, which you failed to do here. (The code you have shown does not appear to make much sense though anyway, because with `"<img alt="+'altTag'+" …` you are not even inserting the value of the variable at this point, you are inserting the literal _text_ `altTag`, so the result of this will only ever be `<img alt=altTag src=…` anyway.)

Comment: Many thanks CBroe for taking the time.

You are right in that the code above would print out the label not the string value. i was fiddling and posted it in error.

However, Below I have the script that works, in that it passes the correct image to the editor but notice what it does tot he alt tag value.

Comment: function onClose(){
 
  var imgUrl = hidFileName.value;
  var altTag = "this is a test";
  
   var result="<img src="+'<%=strImagePath%>'+imgUrl+" alt="+altTag+" >";
   
   var element = window.opener.CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( result );
   var CKEDITOR   = window.opener.CKEDITOR;   
   for ( var i in CKEDITOR.instances ){
      var currentInstance = i;
      break;
   }
   
   var oEditor   = window.opener.CKEDITOR.instances[currentInstance];     
   oEditor.insertElement(element);
   window.close();
  }

Comment: The result

<p><img a="" alt="this" is="" src="http://localhost/ECS_RV_03A_CKEditor-4/Local_IMG_Pallet/astrid.jpg" test="" /></p>

I really appreciate your help :-)

Comment: Yes, because the proper delimiters are missing. You need to wrap the value in either `"` or `'`. The quotes you have in there right now, are part of the JavaScript syntax, they don’t make it into the string value that you are creating.

Comment: Ok, please can you give me an example?

var altTag = "this is a test";    or here   alt="+altTag+"  ? 

Kind regards

Comment: For example `alt='"+altTag+"' >"`, so that you would get single quotes around the attribute value in the generated HTML string.

Comment: Dude, that did it :-) and now I see it too.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I am new to this but spent years on EE where one gives points as rewards. Can't see any form of closing the question as solved. Let me know if I should do anything else. :-)